# Decoding non standard characters to UTF 8 in Python

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I have a program that takes in byte-encoded text via a webhook in Django (written in Python). I have decoding from byte -> utf-8 working for normal letters, but it breaks when an apostrophe ( ' ) is sent in. I have this written to decode the text:

```
encoded = request.body
decoded = parse_qs(encoded)
body = decoded[b'body'][0].decode("utf-8")
```

And this is the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'd like for it to successfully decode apostrophes. I'm also concerned it might break if an emoji is sent in, so I'd like to be able to escape emoji and random chars like ∫, but still preserve the real words in the message.

Comment: What do you mean by "decoding from byte -> utf-8"? UTF-8 is a way of encoding Unicode text as a sequence of bytes, so you can encode a Unicode string to UTF-8 bytes, or you can decode UTF-8 bytes to a Unicode string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parse_qs` will work with decoded utf strings but chokes on non-ascii bytes. For example:

This fails:

```
a = b'restaurant_type=caf\xc3\xa9'
urllib.parse.parse_qs(a)
# > UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3...etc
```

but this works okay:

```
a = b'restaurant_type=caf\xc3\xa9'
urllib.parse.parse_qs(a.decode())
# > {'restaurant_type': ['café']}
```

Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, thank you - I think I was doing parse and decode in the wrong order.