# Django Request.GET and Unicode

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unicode

How can I decode value from request.GET if it in unicode?

```
def find_streets(request, qs=None):
    city_name = request.GET.get('city_name')
    print(request.GET.get('city_name'))
    # %u041C%u043E%u0441%u043A%u0432%u0430
    # (Москва)
    qs = models.Streets.objects.values_list('street_name', flat=True).filter(city__city_name=city_name)
```

If I filtering english word - I successfully get results, but if I filter russian word - result is empty. 
For example, russian word `Москва` returns from request.GET in unicode as:

> %u041C%u043E%u0441%u043A%u0432%u0430

Encoding this to utf-8 returns the same value.

How to convert `%u041C%u043E%u0441%u043A%u0432%u0430` into `Москва` or how to filter DB data using this unicode value?

Comment: Where did this value come from in the first place?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i found a solution, Problem was in JS code. Your question helped me to find error!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. Problem was not in Python but in my JS code (escape() function). I replaced it with  encodeURI().

ex. `var url = "find_streets?city_name=" +  encodeURI(cityName);`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in this post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45385471/7473847)

You could use urllib like this exemple:

```
a = b'restaurant_type=caf\xc3\xa9'
urllib.parse.parse_qs(a.decode())
# > {'restaurant_type': ['café']}
```

In your case, it could be:

```
def find_streets(request, qs=None):
    city_name_tmp = request.GET.get('city_name')
    city_name = urllib.parse.parse_qs(city_name.decode())
    qs = models.Streets.objects.values_list('street_name', flat=True).filter(city__city_name=city_name)
```

Could you try and give me the result ?

Comment: Hi. I found error in my JS code - see my answer below. But for education i tried to use your code in my case and get error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`. city_name has a string type. I tried city_name_tmp.encode().decode() and   get empty result